# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 23, Size: 22

Tags: java

I am parsing pdf files in text documents to create JSON array later.

I am trying to process an arrayList to add something like `marker` to it when this case occurs (where the error appeares the case still has not occured). The loop is being run 21 time til the error occurs. This case  where `prevElement` string equal to the `direction` string is being entered once before the error occurs so I dont understand why this error appears since it was already entered before and alle variables matches.

The `bufferDirection` has 130 strings.

How can I fix it?

I appreciate any help.

**The first time when the if (prevElement.equals(direction)) is entered**

[image]

**Second time before the error appears:**

[image]

**The content of the direcArray before the error appears:**

[image]

```
        ArrayList<String> direcArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        boolean dontAdd = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < bufferDirection.size(); i++) {

            String bufferLine2 = bufferDirection.get(i);

            if (bufferLine2.equals(route)) {
                direcArray.add(bufferLine2);
                String prevElement = bufferDirection.get(i - 1);
                if (prevElement.equals(direction)) {
                    String addElem = bufferDirection.get(i + 1);
                    direcArray.add(i + 1, addElem);

                } else if (!(prevElement.equals(start))) {

                    if (dontAdd) {
                        dontAdd = false;
                        // direcArray.add(i - 1, " ");
                        direcArray.add(i - 1, "New direction");

                    }

                }

            }
```

Comment: Unrelated, but calling something an array when it's not an array is misleading.

Comment: ok thnaks I will conside that in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is

```
direcArray.add(i + 1, addElem);
```

You try to add  `addElem` to index `i + 1`
But the size of `direcArray` is smaller than `bufferDirection`, and at that time, there are `<= i` elements in `direcArray`

Probably, you just want:

```
direcArray.add(addElem);
```

Similarly, the same issue will happen here

```
direcArray.add(i - 1, "New direction");
```

You need to change it to smt like this:

```
direcArray.add(direcArray.size() - 2, "New direction");
```

Comment: I have changed it to `direcArray.add(addElem);` but the error appears at this line `direcArray.add(i - 1, "New direction");`

Comment: @MrAsker as I just said in my answer, you need to change both line.

Comment: `direcArray.add(i - 1, "New direction"); `what should I changed the `i` in this  line  with I have tried with `i+1` and `i-1` but the index and size error still appears.

Comment: @MrAsker please see the suggestion in my answer. It was just updated.

Comment: Yes, your suggestion works for me but this one `direcArray.add("New direction");` works too.

Comment: @MrAsker I just suggested it based on your logic, you want to add `New direction` before  `bufferLine2`. Of course just `add` without `index` will work, but it will add `New direction` to the end of the list. If this is not what you want, so just use `direcArray.add("New direction")`. This is my suggestion, as I am not sure what do you really want :).

Answer (score 2):

Change upper bound on for loop to

```
i < bufferDirection.size() - 1
```

Inside your loop, you are accessing element `i + 1` which will throw the exception; `i` by itself will reach the last index of your array, so i + 1 will put it out of bounds.

Comment: I added `i < bufferDirection.size() -1` but the error is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are adding at pos 23 instead of 22. Use extra index j to keep the next position in the arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

The problem it's that you are trying to add an element in a position that it's not in your `directArray`:

You are adding 2 times a value, one in the loop and one in the line when you add a new Element. This line:

```
direcArray.add(i + 1, addElem);
```

should be:

```
 direcArray.add(i, addElem);
```

I expect it helps to you!

**EDIT:** You should make a condition to solve this issue in the line that you have the problem:

```
if(i + 1 >= bufferDirection.size())
{
   direcArray.add(i, addElem);
}
else
{
   direcArray.add(i + 1, addElem);
}
```